# Authorisation framework for GAE Java

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-security, jersey, jaas, shiro

I am trying to choose an auth framework for GAE and would be very interested in other people's experiences on this subject.

I had a look into [Shiro](http://www.gdevelop.com/blog/2010/12/apache-shiro-on-appengine/) and Spring-Security so far. What could you recommend?

Comment: You'll probably get more answers if you explain what you want it to do. If you don't have any requirements, why use one at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luke Taylor wrote a good [blog post](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/) explaining how to use Spring Security and GAE together. I believe that both Shiro and Spring Security would be suitable for GAE so it's really a question of what you need. Shiro is simple to implement but limited. In contrast Spring Security is a lot more powerful but this brings some additional complexity. Having said that, recent releases have been much simpler to use (especially since the introduction of namespaces).

Personally I would go for Spring

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer. The one problem I worry about SpringSecurity, that it would force us to use the rest of Spring. So I wonder, can we use SpringSecurity without adding dependency on the rest of Spring framework. How much does it make sense?

Comment: You will need to use the spring framework for spring security itself because internally spring security uses spring. However you don't need to use spring for the rest of your application as spring security can be used to secure any http request or method invocation. For example I have successfully used spring security to secure the server side elements of a GWT app.

Comment: We decided to go with Shiro at the end. Jersey+Shiro+GAE+Guice+Objectify4 they play very well together

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go with **GAE + Guice (ligthweight dependecy injection by Google) + Objectify 5 + JAx-Rs implementation (RestEasy or Jersey) + Shiro.**

You can find a good example over here - http://hackersv.blogspot.de/2014/02/shiro-guice-maven-and-google-app-engine.html

Answer (score 0):

[Jello-framework](http://jello-framework.com/guide/authorization.html) is a new Java framework for Google App Engine that includes comprehensive Data Authorization model. One of Jello's key features is its inline Authorization Model. With Jello you can assign different access levels for data elements at any resolution (Namespaces, Entities, Fields, Actions) and specify who is authorized to access the data via the REST API.